# Wildcards in Java PreparedStatements

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

Here's my current SQL statement:

```
SEARCH_ALBUMS_SQL = "SELECT * FROM albums WHERE title LIKE ? OR artist LIKE ?;";
```

It's returning exact matches to the album or artist names, but not anything else. I can't use a '%' in the statement or I get errors.

How do I add wildcards to a prepared statement?

(I'm using Java5 and MySQL)

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a [better version of the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8247970/154527).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You put the % in the bound variable.  So you do

```
   stmt.setString(1, "%" + likeSanitize(title) + "%");
   stmt.setString(2, "%" + likeSanitize(artist) + "%");
```

You should add **ESCAPE '!'** to allow you to escape special characters that matter to **LIKE** in you inputs.

Before using **title** or **artist** you should sanitize them (as shown above) by escaping special characters (**!**, **%**, **_**, and **[**) with a method like this:

```
public static String likeSanitize(String input) {
    return input
       .replace("!", "!!")
       .replace("%", "!%")
       .replace("_", "!_")
       .replace("[", "![");
}
```

Comment: So, what if the bound variable actually had a '%' character in it?

Comment: @Eric - Then you don't need to add it.  There's nothing magical about doing it in the setString rather than anywhere else.

Comment: If your bound variable has a literal '%' you should escape it as '\%'.  See Java method java.lang.String.replace().

Comment: @BillKarwin backslash isn't documented as an escape character for this purpose.  If you include **ESCAPE '!'** and replace **%** with **!%**, **_** with `!_`, and **[** with **![** it should mostly mitigate the SQL injection risk here.

Comment: @BillKarwin my mistake. OP said MySQL which defaults ESCAPE to backslash so you are completely right.  Still good to be explicit for portability: Postgres and MySQL agree here, but Transact SQL docs are silent on its default.

Comment: @AlainO'Dea I disagree with your edit. You don't need to sanitize the input in a bound variable.

Comment: @PaulTomblin the bound variable is itself interpreted as a mix of data and control instructions. Try this with a user input that contains a **%** and see if it works as expected. I would want my program to match content with **%** in it rather than allowing the user supplied **%** to be treated as a wild card.  Does that make sense?

Comment: What about the other replacements? Are `_` treated as something other than a literal `_`?

Comment: @PaulTomblin once **ESCAPE '!'** is specified then **!** becomes a special character.  I added **[** in case it is run on a Transact SQL engine (MSSQL) which uses that to start a character class.  In retrospect that's out of scope since the OP is targeting MySQL explicitly.

Comment: @PaulTomblin **_** is a single character wildcard.