# SQL exception when trying make an prepared statement

Tags: java, sql

I'm trying to pass the following `String` to a `PreparedStatement`:

```
private static final String QUICK_SEARCH = "select * from c where NAME like '% ? %'";
```

However, I get an SQL exception that the bind variable is missing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can we see the actual code that you're using to create this prepared statement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wildcards in Java PreparedStatements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327765/wildcards-in-java-preparedstatements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't u make use of parameters inside of using string concatenation ?

Comment: Be careful. This may enable SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put binding variables inside a string like that.

You need to use:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
```

or similar, depending on what functions are supported by your version of SQL.

Answer (score 1):

cool,

i just set the % signs when setting preparedstatement;

```
pstmt.setString(1, "%" + name + "%");
```