# Using "like" wildcard in prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am using prepared statements to execute mysql database queries. And I want to implement a search functionality based on a keyword of sorts.

For that I need to use `LIKE` keyword, that much I know. And I have also used prepared statements before, but I do not know how to use it with `LIKE` because from the following code where would I add the `'keyword%'`?

Can I directly use it in the `pstmt.setString(1, notes)` as `(1, notes+"%")` or something like that. I see a lot of posts on this on the web but no good answer anywhere.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(
      "SELECT * FROM analysis WHERE notes like ?");
pstmt.setString(1, notes);
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 329, accepted):

You need to set it in the value itself, not in the prepared statement SQL string.

So, this should do for a prefix-match:

```
notes = notes
    .replace("!", "!!")
    .replace("%", "!%")
    .replace("_", "!_")
    .replace("[", "![");
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT * FROM analysis WHERE notes LIKE ? ESCAPE '!'");
pstmt.setString(1, notes + "%");
```

or a suffix-match:

```
pstmt.setString(1, "%" + notes);
```

or a global match:

```
pstmt.setString(1, "%" + notes + "%");
```

Comment: +1  The OP could "set" it in the SQL — as by `... LIKE '%' || ? || '%'` or similar — but that's much less flexible.

Comment: how do i do it with NON-CASE SENSITIVE mode? :)

Comment: Non-case-sensitive can still use `WHERE UPPER(?) LIKE UPPER(?)` when using `pstmt.setString(2, "%" + notes + "%")`

Comment: What if the String **notes** contains a `%` character?

Comment: This is vulnerable to trivial SQL injection attacks.  They may only broaden the scope of returned values but could easily DoS the database by stuffing piles of `%this%that%theother%` into the query making it very heavy to service.  Adding `ESCAPE '!'` to the query and running `notes = notes.replace("!", "!!").replace("_", "!_").replace("[", "![")` prior to supplying **notes** as a parameter improves things.  Using a full text query mechanism which handles these intricacies directly for you is best.

Comment: Edited answer to include SQL injection avoidance.

Comment: @Alain: Thank you. Just wondering, does this apply to all RDBMS the world is aware of? Perhaps `'%' || ? || '%'` as mentioned in 1st comment was better, after all? I don't have the opportunity to experiment right now.

Comment: @BalusC this applies to MSSQL, Postgres, and MySQL in my testing. The String being made into a parameter is itself interpreted as a mix of data and control instructions. SQL concatenation occurs before it is interpreted and preserves the vulnerability. The IEEE Center for Secure Design says to [Strictly Separate Data and Control Instructions, and Never Process Control Instructions Received from Untrusted Sources](http://cybersecurity.ieee.org/2015/11/13/strictly-separatedata-and-control-instructions-and-never-process-control-instructions-received-from-untrusted-sources/).

Comment: I've used the `'%' || ? || '%'` in PostgreSQL consistently without problems. Against Sybase ASE 15.7 I was getting very weird, non reproducible erratic behavior (from JDBC), sometimes working, sometimes not. After I switched to setting `?` to be `"%"+str"%"` I had no more issues.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus The discussion here is not about whether or not this works - this will work with most SQL backends - but whether or not it is secure (it will _not_ be secure with most SQL backends, unless you have one that recognizes this construct and does the escaping for you, which would be highly sketchy).

Comment: Why do you escape the "[" char, please?

Comment: @dpelisek: because it's a special character for `LIKE`. If your DB doesn't consider it a special character, then feel free to remove it (or replace the DB).

Comment: @BalusC Could you please help me? Why are you escaping characters when you're using prepared statement? As far as I know, prepared statements decrease the probability of SQL-injection to none

Comment: @JustLearn: I'm not escaping the prepared statement. I'm escaping the LIKE value. It's to avoid a mismatch caused by characters considered special to the LIKE clause such as `%`, `_` and `[`. Otherwise when you search for e.g. `foo_bar` it would incorrectly match e.g. `fooxbar`.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't seem secure at all. The user might end their string with a % sign and get access to all results in the database that *contain* stuff, not just those that are starting with that particular string.

Comment: Uh, this is exactly why the characters are escaped.

Answer (score 49):

We can use the `CONCAT` SQL function.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(
      "SELECT * FROM analysis WHERE notes like CONCAT( '%',?,'%')";
pstmt.setString(1, notes);
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

This works perfectly for my case.

Comment: `.. notes like '%' || ? || '%'` also works

Comment: Sadly, not working in H2 2.2.220. A `%` in the argument given to a prepared statement as shown is interpreted as another wildcard, not as a character that shall be escaped. 
For the syntax of the argument to `LIKE`, see [Like Predicate Right Hand Side](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html?highlight=escape&search=ESCAPE#like_predicate_right_hand_side).

Answer (score 37):

Code it like this:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(
    "SELECT * FROM analysis WHERE notes like ?");
pstmt.setString(1, notes + "%");`
```

Make sure that you **DO NOT** include the quotes ' ' like below as they will cause an exception.

```
pstmt.setString(1,"'%"+ notes + "%'");
```

Comment: Though it sounds like someone won't run into this assumption, it's actually very valid especially when working with Oracle. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 7):

```
PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement("Select * from Users where User_FirstName LIKE ?");
ps.setString(1, name + '%');
```

Try this out.

Answer (score 0):

```
String fname = "Sam\u0025";

PreparedStatement ps= conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE User_FirstName LIKE ? ");

ps.setString(1, fname);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate the answer rather than just giving the answer? See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -21):

```
String query="select * from test1 where "+selected+" like '%"+SelectedStr+"%';";


PreparedStatement preparedStatement=con.prepareStatement(query);


// where seleced and SelectedStr are String Variables in my program
```

Comment: it is unsafe, kindly use parametrized preparedstatement.

Comment: https://jsparrow.github.io/rules/use-parameterized-query.html#description