# java.sql.SQLException Parameter index out of range

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-error-1064

While am using this code it shows `java.sql.SQLException Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)`:

```
private void cmd_searchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
try{

 String sql = "select * from STD where Name like '%?%' ";
      pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      pst.setString(1,TXT_STUDENTNAME.getText());
      String value=TXT_STUDENTNAME.getText();
      rs=pst.executeQuery();
       jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

             }catch(Exception e){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
   }        
}
```

How can i recover from this exception?

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the wildcard from the sql and add it to the value:

```
String sql = "select * from STD where Name like ? ";
pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1,"%"+TXT_STUDENTNAME.getText()+"%");
```

[Similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247970/using-like-wildcard-in-prepared-statement)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void cmd_searchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
try{

 String sql = "select * from STD where Name like '%?%' ";
      String strStudentName = TXT_STUDENTNAME.getText();
      pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      pst.setString(1,strStudentName );
      rs=pst.executeQuery();
       jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

             }catch(Exception e){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
   }        
}
```

I think this will help you..

**String strStudentName = TXT_STUDENTNAME.getText();
pst.setString(1,strStudentName );**