# Issue with wildcards in Java prepared statements

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I currently confused at how to set wildcards for long values when using select in databases. Currently I have:

```
preparedstatement= conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM database WHERE LONGVALUES LIKE ? ");

preparedstatement.setLong(1, aLongValue);
```

I am currently confused on how to use a wild card to get the results that I want. What I want to select is all values from that database whose `LONGVALUES` column contains the number `aLongValue`. So if `52` is in the database entering `5` or `2` would select it.

Comment: Not sure what the datatype of `LONGVALUES` is.  If it's a numeric type, then it doesn't make sense to use a `LIKE` operator with it.  If it's a character type, then you shouldn't be using `setLong` in the Java code.

Comment: Seems to be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247970/using-like-wildcard-in-prepared-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do `LIKE` on a numerical value. It must be a string so you should either make `LONGVALUES` a VARCHAR field or use a scalar function to convert the value to a string *in line* with your query i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM database WHERE TO_CHAR(LONGVALUES) LIKE ?;
```

Comment: So would it be like this?

preparedstatement= conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM database WHERE TO_CHAR(LONGVALUES) LIKE ? ");

preparedstatement.setChar(1, '%'+aLongValue)+'%');

Comment: I think you would have to construct the parameter when you are doing the setting e.g. `preparedstatement.setString(1, "%" + aLongValue + "%")`.

Answer (score -1):

To use LIKE, your aLongValue should be a varchar, then you can run a ... where longvalues like '%5%'

Comment: The question remains what is the OP actually trying to do? It doesn't strike me as likely that he should really change the column definition willy-nilly just to suit this possibly ill-defined problem.