# What is the use of % in MySQL LIKE function

Tags: php, mysql

When i was learning search function with PHP and MySQL there was a query code  :

```
SELECT id, category, location
FROM table
WHERE
(
    category LIKE '%keyword%'
    OR location LIKE '%keyword%'
)
```

I couldn't understand by % is used in the query and with the escape characters, is the `%keyword%` has to changed with `%$variable%`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%` is a placeholder for an arbitrary string.

So if you have something `WHERE category LIKE '%keyword%'` this will return all categories that contain the word 'keyword'.

I guess what you are looking for is to find something that contains a given keyword, and the keyword is in your variable, so that would be `WHERE category LIKE '%$variable%'`, with `$variable` being the variable that holds the keyword. There are some issues of course with this, like the keyword cannot contain `%` itself, otherwise it will have to be escaped and there is the issue of possible SQL injection, which should be approached by using [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247970/using-like-wildcard-in-prepared-statement), but those issues seem a bit outside of the scope of the question.

Comment: and what's with the variable (see question).

Comment: so, then should i use % for variables or not ?

Comment: I don't understand what you meant by that, sorry. If you are worried about escaping, then you probably should use prepared statements.

Comment: i mean then i should use `WHERE category LIKE '%$variable%'` or `WHERE category LIKE '$variable'`

Comment: That depends on what you want. But at the end, the resulting query will be the content of your variable put in the string, so if your variable contains `bunny` then `WHERE category LIKE '%$variable%'` will become `WHERE category LIKE '%bunny%'`. You could also add the `%` to the string in the $variable first and leave it out in the WHERE and have the same resulting string