# SQL with variable in LIKE statement: Invalid column Index

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, sql-like, setstring

I'm using Oracle.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM BookLoanInfo WHERE title LIKE '%?%' ORDER BY bid");
ResultSet rs;
String bookstring = scan.nextLine();
try{
    pstmt.clearParameters();
    pstmt.setString(1, bookstring);
    rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

The actual problem seems to be with either the `setString` or how I have typed the query.

This however gives Invalid Column Index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to specify the wildcards as part of your `setString` statement.

[Wildcard in Prepared Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247970/using-like-wildcard-in-prepared-statement)