# JDBC Error for prepared Statement giving SQL exception. Why?

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to compile a java file in the format:

```
PreparedStatement var = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%?%';");

var.setString(1, string);
var.executeQuery();
```

However, it is not compiling, with the following errors. Can anyone explain why I am getting these errors?

```
BookPurchase.java:97: error: unreported exception SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
            con.prepareStatement(
                                ^
BookPurchase.java:100: error: unreported exception SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
            searchResults.setString(1, keyword);
                                   ^
BookPurchase.java:101: error: unreported exception SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
            searchResults.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: `LIKE '%?%'` will not work. Read the JDBC tutorial to find out how to properly use a prepared statement parameter: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 4):

That is because the `prepareStatement` is declared to [throw](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/declaring.html) an Exception.

To overcome your problem enclose your code in a [try](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) / [catch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html) block:

```
try {
    PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(mySql);
    var.setString(1, string);
    var.executeQuery();
}catch(SQLException ex){
    //deal with exception
}
```

or you can make your method that executes this code **throw** an Exception:

```
public void myMethod() throws SQLException {
    ...
    ...
    PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(mySql);
    var.setString(1, string);
    var.executeQuery();
    ...
    ...
}
```

This is the most basic on exception-handling in java. You can refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) for more info

Answer (score -1):

Try that:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE = ?;
```

then, set String as:
    var.setString(1, "%"+string+"%");

It should work fine.

Look also here:
[Using "like" wildcard in prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247970/using-like-wildcard-in-prepared-statement)

Comment: You are right, but that has nothing to do with the compiler errors which the question is about - but it will lead to the next question.