# Mybatis - preventing agains SQL Injection in LIKE query

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, mybatis

I am using `sql server`. Lets look following query in `mybatis`:
`param` is type of string, in database `SomeColumn` is type of `VARCHAR`

```
...
 = SomeColumn LIKE '%#{param, jdbcType=VARCHAR}%'
```

It returns error:

> org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is
>   org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not set parameters for
>   mapping: ParameterMapping{property='param', mode=IN, javaType=class
>   java.lang.Object, jdbcType=VARCHAR, numericScale=null,
>   resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}. Cause:
>   org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for
>   parameter #1 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for
>   this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause:
>   org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for
>   parameter #1 with JdbcType VARCHAR . Try setting a different JdbcType for
>   this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause:
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 1 is out of
>   range.

I can't deal with it (any ideas?), but I find something:

```
...    
<bind name="param" value="'%' + param + '%'" />
...
     = SomeColumn LIKE #{param}
```

And it does work. I think that prevent me agains `SQL Injection` but I am not sure. Can you answer to it ? Is it `SQL Injection` safe ?

Comment: You'll need to escape all `%` in your parameter before concatenating the ones you want on to the beginning and end. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247970/using-like-wildcard-in-prepared-statement

Comment: Ok, but tell me if my approach with `bind` is SQLInjection safe ?

Comment: And could you show me how to escape it in your way? This example doesn't help me

Comment: I have lately learned another way to do it:`LIKE '%'+#{param}+'%'`, that does not need escaping `%` in the param. About injection: as long as the param value is not concatenated with the query (and then parsed and executed), but bound as parameter, it should be ok.

Comment: @blackwizard you way works for me. Simply, database engine before using LIKE filter evalues expression.  My solution is not clear for me: `<bind name="param" value="'%' + param + '%'" />`. From what it does know that `param` in `value="'%' + param + '%'"` refers to external variable ?

Answer (score 3):

We faced the same issue and the below method worked for us:

e.g select * from TABLE1 where COLUMN1 like '%' || #{PARAM_NAME} || '%';

This prevents SQL Injection and allows to use # in LIKE query.