# A row missing when doing the search from sql table

Tags: java, sql

[Using "like" wildcard in prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247970/using-like-wildcard-in-prepared-statement) I still didn't get why I lost a row with this question, Can anyone help me?

As the code below if I search the object contain "N" from the sql command  the result will be 4 [This picture is what the result suppose to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iu7ss.jpg)

However when I run the code, the first row will always disappear [This picture is the result I've got when I run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOWTC.jpg)

I am new to JDBC, Thank You

```
   String query = "select * from item where title like ?";
    String search = SearchItemText.getText();
    if (SearchItemText.getText().isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Search cannot leave blank");
    } else {
        ArrayList<String> item = new ArrayList<>();
        try (
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
                PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);) {
            {
                pstmt.setString(1, "%" + search + "%");

                ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
                if (rs.next() == false) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, search + " is not exist, try "
                            + "switch to uppercase or lowercase");
                }
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String item_no = rs.getString("item_no");
                    String title = rs.getString("title");
                    String number_available = rs.getString("number_available");
                    item.add(item_no + "," + title + "," + number_available);
                    Object o = item_no + " " + title + " Stock = " + number_available;
                    System.out.println(o);
                    dlm.addElement(o);
                }
            }
            ItemList.setModel(dlm);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So much wrong with this code.

Comment: I know there are lots of the mistakes in my code, first time doing JDBC T^T  any idea how to fix it

Comment: The below block of code makes your resultset first record to move.         if (rs.next() == false) {
                  ......
                }                                                                                                    Sample :                                                                                                   if (executeQuery.next() == false) {
                    System.out.println("Calling false block");
                }else{
                 System.out.println("True and reads first record");
             }