# How to combine random variable with character '%' in Jmeter JDBC Sampler?

Tags: postgresql, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to make workload test in Jmeter.
This is Postgresql and I would like to combine a random variable with '%'.

Could you help me the way to make sql query?

[image]

I have already tried with '?%', but there is an error "The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.".

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is switching to `Select Statement` and amend your query to look like:

```
SELECT * FROM scloud_usr.tcus_usr_rgn where UID like '${__RandomString(3,ABD,UID)}%'
```

---

If you want to continue with the `Prepared Select Statement` you need to add this `%` wildcard to the **parameter value itself**, not in the query, i.e.

[image: JMeter Prepared Statement Wildcard]

More information:

- [Using “like” wildcard in prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247970/using-like-wildcard-in-prepared-statement)
- [Performance Testing BLOB from a MySQL Database with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-testing-blob-from-a-mysql-database-with-jmeter)
- [Prepared statements with % wildcards](https://coderanch.com/t/300966/databases/Prepared-statements-wildcards)