# How do I properly filter results from MySQL using a form?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

What is the proper way to filter results? What I have got so far is form where you can input firstname, lastname, phone and rest of stuff. How do I make statement ignore empty input fields instead of searching values which are empty?

I'm using prepared statements and when I filter stuff I use `WHERE firstname = ? and lastname = ?` and conditions change statement if something is empty. How can I prevent making hundreds of statements with conditions?

```
$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM cust");

    if(!empty($firstname) && !empty($lastname)) {
        $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM cust WHERE as_first = ? AND as_last = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $firstname, $lastname);
    } else if(!empty($firstname) && empty($lastname)) {
        $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM cust WHERE as_first = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $firstname);
    } else if(empty($firstname) && !empty($lastname)) {
        $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM cust WHERE as_last = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $lastname);
    }
```

Comment: Do you have an example of your code thus far?

Comment: Hello, can you please include code from php file and html file to see how are you populating (using js from client side with ajax or directly from server side). thanks

Comment: I think this covers it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247970/using-like-wildcard-in-prepared-statement

Comment: Yes, added. Took a while as I am on mobile and cloud ide didn't support a phone.

Comment: How can I prevent making hundreds of statements with conditions? Is clear in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you should write your own conditions, like:

```
$sql = 'SELECT...' // your original query
$sql .= !empty($phone) ? ' phone = :phone';
```

and binding params manually:

```
if (!empty($phone)) {
    $stmt->bindParam(':phone', '%'.$phone.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Resolved the issue. Your method is better.

Comment: @Epz in the long run, you may want to use some decent ORM, but it's a good thing to start with the basics. Keep up the enthusiasm!