# SQL Error SQLSTATE[42000] on LIKE operation

Tags: php, mysql

I want to use a simple query for search.

This query is working fine in another page and with another table.
I just copied and pasted it.

Here is query

```
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM _all_users WHERE fullname LIKE '%".$q."%' OR mobile LIKE '%".$q."%' ORDER BY time_stamp DESC");
    $stmt->execute();
```

It must be working. But im getting this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OR‌ mobile LIKE '%848%' ORDER BY time_stamp DESC LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0' at line 1 in /var/www/_am/ajax/getLists.php:171 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/_am/ajax/getLists.php(171): PDO->prepare('SELECT * FROM _...') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/_am/ajax/getLists.php on line 171

Any idea?

Comment: What is the value of `$q`? What does the query look like after the variables are interpolated?

Comment: Please read about **[SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)**. Instead of building queries with string concatenation, use **[prepared statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)** with **[bound parameters](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)**. See **[this page](https://phptherightway.com/#databases)** and **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)** for some good examples.

Comment: Both integer and string. I give same error for both.

Comment: I don't think `$q` contains what you think it does. Can you please post an actual query that generates that error message?

Comment: I knwo about injection this is why Im using pdo. This question is just about syntax error not security.

Comment: Security always matters and we take it seriously here. If you post insecure code we will *always* point it out. You aren't the only one reading this question and its comments. Letting insecure go unchallenged hurts everyone who reads this question.

Comment: John conde you can see an example of a $q value in error.

Comment: Please just show **the entire query**. It's that not hard to do. If you want our help you should do what we ask. We're doing *you* a favor. Please respect that and provide us with what we need to actually help you. In fact, you should show the code that builds that query, too.

Comment: string(3) "848"...Here it is.

Comment: Never mind. If you can't provide what I asked for I can't help you. Good luck.

Comment: There's little point in preparing a query if you are just going to concatenate the variables into the query string. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247970/using-like-wildcard-in-prepared-statement), which might also help with your problem

Comment: @roberthofer From reading the above comments: understand that using PDO does not itself protect you from SQL injection. Using prepared statements will only protect you from SQL injection if you use bound parameters. Using `prepare` on a query that has no bound parameters (as you have done here) provides no protection at all.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM _all_users (WHERE fullname LIKE '%".$q."%' OR mobile LIKE '%".$q."%') ORDER BY time_stamp DESC");
    $stmt->execute();
```

or

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM _all_users WHERE (fullname LIKE '%".$q."%' OR mobile LIKE '%".$q."%') ORDER BY time_stamp DESC");
    $stmt->execute();
```