# Invalid Identifier when using LIKE query in Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to execute a LIKE query in Java using prepared statements but I'm getting the following error

```
 ORA-00904: "%12P1A%": invalid identifier

    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    try {
        connection = DataSourceFactory.getConnection();

        statement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from users where userID like ?");
        statement.setString(1, "%12P1A%");

        resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

        //....

    }catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new DAOException(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        DaoUtil.closeAll(connection, statement, resultSet);
    }
```

May I know why is this incorrect?

For further Information, I'm actually getting '%12P1A%' by some other function so  the code is something like

```
statement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from users where userID like ?");
statement.setString(1, getValue());
```

the query parses to something like

```
select * from users where userID like '%12P1A%'
```

but it is throwing MISSING IN or OUT Paramter. Idk why it is not picking the value. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's correct; at least the two lines you showed us are correct.  Please include the full code.

Comment: Column userID data type? (Is it really a character type?!?)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that's exactly what I'm trying to run, rest is just executing query in try catch. @ jarlh  yup it is a varchar

Comment: `statement` must be a `PreparedStatement` and the query must be `statement.executeQuery()` (without repeating the SQL string). Also `statement` should not be a field, but rather a local variable to prevent concurrent usage.

Comment: Hint: I am not the Java expert, but I am able to reproduce the issue when a string literal is wrapped with double quotes: `select * from dual where 1 like "%12P1A%"` -- ORA-00904: "%12P1A%": invalid identifier -- It must be passed as `'%12P1A%'` -- If it helps

Comment: @Tejash Prepared statements don't work this way.  _No_ double quotes would be bound in this case.

Comment: No double quotes in SQL are for for column names officially, and single quotes for strings.

Comment: CORRECT code, try `select * from users where userID like '%12P1A%'`

Comment: "I'm getting the following error" - which error?

Comment: Can you just try with this: `statement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from users where userID like '%' || ? || '%'"); statement.setString(1, "12P1A");` -- See this if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247970/using-like-wildcard-in-prepared-statement

Comment: "it is throwing MISSING IN or OUT Paramter. " - please note that statements like this don't help that much. If you're asking about exceptions or errors you should always post the entire message along with the stacktrace if possible (post it as a code block to keep the formatting).

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the value between `'%` and `%'` that you are getting from the input and then create your query as -

```
statement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from users where userID like '%" + <value-from-some-other-method> + "%'");
```

If there is an option, ask the method response to be the value directly instead of having it formatted for query parameter.